# Is it possible to send data between mobile phones whithout an access point?

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming

I'm working on a project that can help optimize multicast. More precisely an implementation of Network Coding.

I have a great deal of it done in simulators, but now that I want to implement it on actual mobile phones, I'm facing this problem: How can I send data between them phones without the need for access points between them?

Can I open sockets programmatically and listen to them? Or is there something like an AdHoc  network (those are no longer supported in android) that I can use?

**EDIT**: If needed I can rely on a server/access point for DHCP and such (for the phones to know of each other) . But the data needs to flow between the phones independently of the access point.

Comment: you can use Bluetooth SPP for example...

Answer (score 0):

An access point is just a 1st-level ISO/OSI device that permits to one or more WiFi compliant devices to communicate wirelessly. Unless you can use Bluetooth or IR as a fallback, there's no way you could make it without an AP.

Comment: Yes but for the project I am working on . I don't need much of the OSI model. Since I'll be writing my own "routing" . All I need is data to flow form one device to the other

Comment: You need a phisical way of doing it. You have to consider that the electromagnetic waves need something to rely on to "flow" to another device

Comment: Maybe you could come up with some results using your network card in promiscuous mode

Comment: "You need a phisical way of doing it" . Exactly. If I'm not wrong, the antennas are there so there is a physical way. The access points are basically there to "control" this flow of data. But if the phone can control that data flow then it should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

Have one of your phones act as a "mobile hotspot" (a wifi access point) for the other phones. Share the name of the access point and passphrase with the other phones and they will all be connected on the same network (and the internet through the "hotspot" phone's cellular data connection.

In this way, you have all the normal networking capabilities and security available to you without requiring an additional/external access point.

However, this will not result in direct connectivity between the many phones that are not the access point; all (non-multicast) network communication will bounce through the phone that is acting as an access point for your network.